# How to exeecute rxjs request after event?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to execute rxjs request:

```
this.form.get('compact_addr').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    this.searchByAddressParcel.search().subscribe((response) => {
    });
});
```

It forced me to subscribe to outer observer to execute a inner. How to use it inline style and cancel request if it was sent before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

something like this:

```js
this.form.get('compact_addr').valueChanges
.pipe(
   switchMap(() => this.searchByAddressParcel.search())
)
.subscribe((response) => {
   //hits here whenever `searchByAddressParcel` emits
});
```

Comment: May be add a `debounceTime(250), switchMap(() => this.searchByAddressParcel.search())` before triggering the search action in the chain. This helps to avoid service calls to search for partial edits

Comment: Yep you can add debounce too if you wish. OP never asked for that though.